# Getting all Gtalk contacts's status unavailable

Tags: android, google-talk, asmack

I am using asmack api to integrate gtalk with my android application i can login, can send messasges to my contact user, but I want to know all contacts' status whether he/she online or offline, I used roster to know it but showing all users' availability is offline no one appears online, where in fact,  there are some users who are online, want to know what's going wrong. can anyone help? pasting my code below here:

```
Roster roster= connection.getRoster();
        roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.getDefaultSubscriptionMode());
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        Presence presence2;

                for(RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                    presence2 = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

                    System.out.println(entry.getUser());
                    System.out.println(presence2.getType());
                   // System.out.println(presence2.getStatus());
                }
```

have tried with presence2.getMode() too, but it returns null.
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

At what point did you try to get the roster? Did you try presence2.isAvailable()? I also recommend setting a roster listener, otherwise, your list won't be updated when presence is changed on any user.

Comment: then i can't tell for sure what happen without more code. I basically did something similar and i get all the users' presence. was also able to update user's presence when they go online offline

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for my BuddyList class. I passed my gridview to a buddylist class and ran this code in a thread to update the arrays that are attached to an adapter. I know this is a few months old, but figured it would help someone else at some point. Just make sure you call the updateBuddies from a new thread. Be sure to handle closing this thread when you leave the activity hosting the buddylist as well. Cheers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsDVH.png

```
    private void updateBuddies() {
    final Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
    roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {

        @Override
        public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void presenceChanged(Presence arg0) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    addressA.clear();
                    nameA.clear();
                    modeA.clear();
                    availA.clear();
                    statusA.clear();
                    grid.invalidateViews();
                    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                    for(RosterEntry r:entries) {
                        if (r.getName() != null) {
                            String email = r.getUser();
                            String name = r.getName();
                            Presence pres = roster.getPresence(r.getUser());

                            if (pres != null) {
                                addressA.add(email);
                                nameA.add(name);
                                modeA.add(""+pres.getMode());
                                availA.add(""+pres.getType());
                                statusA.add(""+pres.getStatus());   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }});
        }});
    }
```